# Creating a win condition by passing strings in functions

Tags: c

Whenever I compile my code currently it prints all possible scenarios no matter what integer is passed. Any help on how to fix this and why this happens?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void *get_plays(char *player1, char *player2)
{
    printf ("Player 1 chooses to play:   ");
    scanf("%s", player1);
    printf ("Player 2 chooses to play:   ");
    scanf("%s", player2);
    return player1;
    return player2;
}
int *check_for_winner(char *player1, char *player2, int condition)
{

    if (player1==player2){
        condition = 0;
    }
    else if(player1=="rock" && player2 == "scissors"){
        condition = 1;
    }
    else if(player1=="paper" && player2 == "scissors"){
        condition = 2;
    }
    else if(player1=="rock" && player2 == "paper"){
        condition = 2;
    }
    else if(player1=="paper" && player2 == "rock"){
        condition = 1;
    }
    else if(player1=="scissors" && player2 == "papper"){
        condition = 1;
    }
    else (player1=="scissors" && player2 == "rock");{
        condition = 1;
    }
}
void *print_plays(char *player1, char *player2)
{
    printf("Player 1 has played %s \n",player1);
    printf("Player 2 has played %s \n",player2);
}
void *print_winner(int condition)
{
    if (condition = 0){
        printf("It's a tie\n");
    }
    else if (condition = 1){
        printf("Player 1 wins\n");
    }
    else (condition = 2);{
        printf("Player 2 wins\n");
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    char player1[10];
    char player2[10];
    int win;
    get_plays(player1, player2);
    check_for_winner(player1, player2, win);
    print_plays(player1, player2);
    print_winner(win);      
    return;
}
```

When I compile it prints "Player 1 wins" and "Player 2 wins" no clue why or how to fix it or even why it happens. I'm still fairly new to C so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `void *get_plays(char *player1, char *player2) { ... return player1; return player2;}` this doesnt do what you think it does. You will never reach the `return player2`.

Comment: Also here `if (player1==player2){` you are comparing pointers not strings. You really need to understand more `c` before you go through this. Dont guess `c`, learn it from a book.

Comment: `else if(player1=="rock" && player2 == "scissors"){` is the same scenario as above as well.

Comment: `win` un-initialized , you can't have multiple returns like `return player1`; `return player2` only one will get execute.

Comment: is it possible  to used strcmp, if so how do I go about that?

Comment: @pineapplefun101 [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: `void*` tells the compiler that the function returns a `void` pointer. I think you wanted to use `void`. Your code has more issues with the basic language features than the logic. Please consider learning C before programming in C.

Comment: The term "compile" is usually not used to include executing your program. Only running your program will produce the output your are referring to. Being aware of the differences of the build steps of a program is an important skill for anything but the most basic C programming and running is not even considered part of building.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void
get_plays (char *choice1, char *choice2)
{
    printf ("Choices: 'paper' - 'rock' - 'scissors'\n");
    printf ("Player 1 chooses to play: ");
    scanf ("%s", choice1);

    printf ("Player 2 chooses to play: ");
    scanf ("%s", choice2);
}

int
check_for_winner (const char *choice1, const char *choice2)
{
    // paper wins rock but scissors does not and equals itself
    if (strcmp (choice1, "paper") == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp (choice2, "rock") == 0)
            return 1;

        if (strcmp (choice2, "scissors") == 0)
            return 2;

        return 0;
    }

    // rock wins scissors but paper does not and equals itself
    if (strcmp (choice1, "rock") == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp (choice2, "scissors") == 0)
            return 1;

        if (strcmp (choice2, "paper") == 0)
            return 2;

        return 0;
    }

    // scissors wins paper but rock does not and equals itself
    if (strcmp (choice1, "scissors") == 0)
    {
        if (strcmp (choice2, "paper") == 0)
            return 1;

        if (strcmp (choice2, "rock") == 0)
            return 2;

        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    char choice1 [10];
    char choice2 [10];
    int winner;
    char q;

    char *result[3] = {
        "No one is the winner", 
        "Player 1 is the winner!!!", 
        "Player 2 is the winner!!!"
    };

    printf ("Choose 'q' to exit\n");
    printf ("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    while (q != 'q')
    {
        get_plays (&choice1[0], &choice2[0]);
        winner = check_for_winner (choice1, choice2);

        printf ("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf ("The result: %s\n",  result[winner]);
        printf ("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        getc (stdin);
        scanf ("%c", &q);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here I hope the code will help you!